# how cookies property gets set over SSL

Tags: java, ssl, cookies, websphere, cookie-httponly

My application is using websphere 6.1.

And there is no configuration done for setting the cookies secured.

But when I test my application's cookies using mozilla firefox addon : firbug, I can see that few of the cookies are secure and few of them are not.

So I want to know what parameters decides that a cookie should be secure or not.

Sorry for not sharing code / cookie information due to some security constraints.